# How can one get the accuracy of a geocode in python?

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding, geocoder

I have created a script which fetches geocodes(latitudes and longtitudes) of a sample of addresses

However I want it to also return the accuracy/precision of these geocodes that are mined. for example: 100% accurate or 90% etc

```
# Set the input and output files
input_file_path = "geocodi_4k-5250.csv"
output_file_path = "output"  # appends "####.csv" to the file name when it writes the file.

# Set the name of the column indexes here so that pandas can read the CSV file
address_column_name = "ADDRESS"
state_column_name = "STATE"
zip_column_name = "ZIP_CODE"   # Leave blank("") if you do not have zip codes

# Where the program starts processing the addresses in the input file
# This is useful in case the computer crashes so you can resume the program where it left off or so you can run multiple
# instances of the program starting at different spots in the input file
start_index = 0
# How often the program prints the status of the running program
status_rate = 100
# How often the program saves a backup file
write_data_rate = 1000
# How many times the program tries to geocode an address before it gives up
attempts_to_geocode = 3
# Time it delays each time it does not find an address
# Note that this is added to itself each time it fails so it should not be set to a large number
wait_time = 3

# ----------------------------- Processing the input file -----------------------------#

df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, low_memory=False)
# df = pd.read_excel(input_file_path)

# Raise errors if the provided column names could not be found in the input file
if address_column_name not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("Can't find the address column in the input file.")
if state_column_name not in df.columns:
    raise ValueError("Can't find the state column in the input file.")

# Zip code is not needed but helps provide more accurate locations
if (zip_column_name):
    if zip_column_name not in df.columns:
        raise ValueError("Can't find the zip code column in the input file.")
    addresses = (df[address_column_name] + ', ' + df[zip_column_name].astype(str) + ', ' + df[state_column_name]).tolist()
else:
    addresses = (df[address_column_name] + ', ' + df[state_column_name]).tolist()


# ----------------------------- Function Definitions -----------------------------#

# Creates request sessions for geocoding
class GeoSessions:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Arcgis = requests.Session()
        self.Komoot = requests.Session()


# Class that is used to return 3 new sessions for each geocoding source
def create_sessions():
    return GeoSessions()


# Main geocoding function that uses the geocoding package to covert addresses into lat, longs
def geocode_address(address, s):
    g = geocoder.arcgis(address, session=s.Arcgis)
    if (g.ok == False):
        g = geocoder.komoot(address, session=s.Komoot)

    return g


def try_address(address, s, attempts_remaining, wait_time):
    g = geocode_address(address, s)
    if (g.ok == False):
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        s = create_sessions()  # It is not very likely that we can't find an address so we create new sessions and wait
        if (attempts_remaining > 0):
            try_address(address, s, attempts_remaining-1, wait_time+wait_time)
    return g


# Function used to write data to the output file
def write_data(data, index):
    file_name = (output_file_path + str(index) + ".csv")
    print("Created the file: " + file_name)
    done = pd.DataFrame(data)
    done.columns = ['Address', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Provider']
    done.to_csv((file_name + ".csv"), sep=',', encoding='utf8')


# Variables used in the main for loop that do not need to be modified by the user
s = create_sessions()
results = []
failed = 0
total_failed = 0
progress = len(addresses) - start_index

# ----------------------------- Main Loop -----------------------------#

for i, address in enumerate(addresses[start_index:]):
    # Print the status of how many addresses have be processed so far and how many of the failed.
    if ((start_index + i) % status_rate == 0):
        total_failed += failed
        print(
            "Completed {} of {}. Failed {} for this section and {} in total.".format(i + start_index, progress, failed,
                                                                                     total_failed))
        failed = 0

    # Try geocoding the addresses
    try:
        g = try_address(address, s, attempts_to_geocode, wait_time)
        if (g.ok == False):
            results.append([address, "was", "not", "geocoded"])
            print("Gave up on address: " + address)
            failed += 1
        else:
            results.append([address, g.latlng[0], g.latlng[1], g.provider])

    # If we failed with an error like a timeout we will try the address again after we wait 5 secs
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed with error {} on address {}. Will try again.".format(e, address))
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            s = create_sessions()
            g = geocode_address(address, s)
            if (g.ok == False):
                print("Did not fine it.")
                results.append([address, "was", "not", "geocoded"])
                failed += 1
            else:
                print("Successfully found it.")
                results.append([address, g.latlng[0], g.latlng[1], g.provider])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed with error {} on address {} again.".format(e, address))
            failed += 1
            results.append([address, e, e, "ERROR"])

    # Writing what has been processed so far to an output file
    if (i%write_data_rate == 0 and i != 0):
        write_data(results, i + start_index)

    # print(i, g.latlng, g.provider)


# Finished
write_data(results, i + start_index + 1)
print("Finished! :)")
```

My input file looks like:

```
ADDRESS STATE   ZIP_CODE
21236 Birchwood Loop    AK  99567
1731 Bragaw St  AK  99508
300 E Fireweed Ln   AK  99503
```

Output is:

```
Address Lat Long
21236 Birchwood Loop, 99567, AK 61.40886875 -149.4865564
1731 Bragaw St, 99508, AK   61.20489474 -149.808293
300 E Fireweed Ln, 99503, AK    61.1980295  -149.8783492
```

I want it to also show how accurate the geocodes are.How do I do the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear answer on this. However, some solutions come to mind:

1. Test your geocoding against a standard list (a list with addresses with their correct geocodes). This will tell you how your geocoding performs generally.
2. Try multiple geocoding services. If you have that the geocodes match across services, there is a high chance that the geocode is correct. One thing to be careful about is that you may not have exactly correct matches, so you may have to calculate the distance between the points.

Did you find any other solution to this problem. I'm working on something similar and would like to hear if you have other ideas.

Comment: This answer is a little borderline between being an answer and another question. I suggest you to edit it and make it a little more "assertive". Avoid asking other questions, or otherwise it will be probably flagged as "not an aswer" and eventually deleted. ;) (as a general rule remember this is not a forum, but a Q&A site. Only questions and answers are admitted)